# Why this linear transformation has a basis of eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, polynomials, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider $W$ one $n$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ and $T:W\to W$ one linear transformation such that $T^3 = \mathbf{1}$ where $\mathbf{1}$ is the identity. I've read that this implies that $x^3-1$ divides the minimal polynomial of $T$ and so there is a basis of eigenvectors of $T$.

Now I can't understand what is happening here. Since $T^3 = \mathbf{1}$ we see that if we define $f(x)=x^3-1$ we will have $f(T)=0$. So $f$ is a polynomial with $f(T)=0$ and $f$ is monic.

Now, I don't see why this all implies that $f$ divides the minimal polynomial $\mu$ and furthermore I'm failing to see why $f$ dividing $\mu$ implies that there is a basis of eigenvectors of $T$.

What is the reasoning that leads to all these conclusions here?

Answer (score 4):

It's the minimal polynomial which is a divisor of $x^3-1$. Hence, the minimal polynomial splits into *distinct* linear factors, and this is a criterion for diagonalisability.